# create input box with variable in Crystal Reports (not Visual studios version)

Tags: c#, vb.net, stored-procedures, crystal-reports

I have a stored procedure that requires a DATETIME variable to display the results in crystal reports. How would I create an input text box and pass the variable to the procedure? Is it even possible to program in vb or C# in crystal reports, or do I need visual studio 2008?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crystal Reports will automatically create a parameter field for each parameter in your stored procedure.  You can access these parameter fields in code, if necessary.  If they are not supplied, and you haven't forced the viewer to suppress parameters, the user will be prompted to supply values.  You have some limited flexibility in Crystal Reports to alter the prompting text and supply some default and 'lookup' values, if necessary.